# Satellite tracking telescope integrated program in Matlab

Tags: orbital-mechanics, telescope, sgp4, frames

How can I get a comprehensive, integrated MATLAB program to set up and capture SGP4 output for telescope mounting?

I am currently receiving state vectors from the SGP4 program, which include the `recef` and `vecef` vectors, as well as the `reci`, `veci`, and `rtod` and `vtod`.

I can also call Norad TLE files in my SGP 4 program. Now I have to make a program to prepare the necessary data and send it to the telescope mounting system, which is an alt-azimuth mounting system, but I mean to send it to the telescope mounting motor drivers.

My optical system is a 6-inch f/6.7 Newtonian reflector telescope, and the goal is to use a Canon 700D camera for imaging.

Comment: If you were willing to use Python I can write an answer. Matlab is a black box that one has to pay for over and over, Python is free, open source and incredibly well supported by a huge community of users. Is there some reason you must use Matlab? For example the [Skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) package will manage downloading of TLEs and give you the alt/az or RA/Dec paths of satellites, as well as solar system objects and stars.

Comment: On another note, what implementation of SGP4 are you using exactly? Can you add a link or reference to it? Can you give an explanation of exactly what output is coming from it?

Comment: Hello
Thank you for your help, but now I am only fluent in MATLAB and Simulink, and now I can not learn other programming languages, I also have SGP 4 in MATLAB, and I am looking for an integration program for It and other programs.
For example, inputs, SGP 4 implementations and hardware outputs.

Comment: Okay got it, thanks! You can also have a look in Photography Stack Exchange, they have a very active [astrophotography tag](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophotography) and there are several questions referencing MATLAB there, though mostly for image processing. Can you mention exactly what output your SGP4 calculation provides please? Is it state vectors? If so, what options do you have for frames? Can you access a frame that rotates with Earth? I think you really must add these details to your question. *Thanks!*

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answers. I must say that I am currently receiving state  vectors from the SGP4 program, which include the recef and vecef vectors, as well as the reci, veci, and rtod and
 vtod.
I can also call Norad TLe files in my SGP 4 program. 
Now I have to make a program to prepare the necessary data and send it to the telescope mounting system, which is an alt-azimuth mounting system, but I mean to send it to the telescope mounting motor drivers.

Comment: My optical system is a 6-inch Newtonian reflector telescope with a F-number of 6.3, and the goal is that the digital imaging system used be a Canon 700D camera